# A series representation for the non-analytic function: $\exp(-\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does anyone know about series representation for

**$f(x)=exp(-\frac{1}{x})$**

Since this function is not analytic, Taylor representation doesn't work out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write Taylor at infinity in negative powers, i.e. for $exp(t)$ where $t=\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know about series representation for
>   **$f(x)=exp(-\frac{1}{x})$**?

One may recall that the power series expansion
$$
e^u=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{u^n}{n!}, \quad u \in  \mathbb{C},\tag1
$$ has an **infinite radius of convergence**. Then, using $(1)$ with $u:=-\dfrac1x$, $x \neq 0$, one is allowed to write 
$$
e^{\large -\frac1x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left(\frac1x\right)^n, \quad \text{for all} \,\, x \in \mathbb{C}-\left\{0\right\}, \tag2
$$ giving an answer to your question.

Comment: And the resulting asymptotic series is a Laurent series with an essential singularity at $0$.